# Get Chinese punctuation in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

With the answers in

- [Javascript unicode string, chinese character but no punctuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21109011/javascript-unicode-string-chinese-character-but-no-punctuation) and
- [How can I strip all punctuation from a string in JavaScript using regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328500/how-can-i-strip-all-punctuation-from-a-string-in-javascript-using-regex)

I have gotten close to what I need: get all the Chinese punctuations in the string.

And [Intl.Segmenter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Segmenter) is much better than `String.prototype.split(" ")`

But with one problem `/\p{P}/u.test(segment.segment)` test all the punctuations, not just Chinese punctuation, so I get English punctuation like apostrophe, comma, question mark and period.

I hope I need not to resolve to the answer in [Chinese punctuation Unicode range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68371855/chinese-punctuation-unicode-range). It is too complicated. According to this wiki about [Chinese punctuation](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A0%87%E7%82%B9%E7%AC%A6%E5%8F%B7) there are only about 20.

So is there any easy way to do that ?

```js
const str = "你好，让我们试试这个分词效果，你说怎么样？Let's try Intl.Segmenter, should we ?"
let segmenterZH = new Intl.Segmenter('zh', { granularity: 'grapheme' })
let segments = segmenterZH.segment(str)
for (let segment of segments) {
  if (/\p{P}/u.test(segment.segment)) {
    console.log(`${segment.index}:${segment.segment}`)
  }
}
```

--- update ---

I would like to add some new finding, partially inspired by [Use regular expression to match characters appearing in Traditional Chinese ONLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533231/use-regular-expression-to-match-characters-appearing-in-traditional-chinese-only) :

1. If I want to get all the Chinese character without punctuations, I can use `/\p{sc=Han}/` as https://javascript.info/regexp-unicode said.
2. I further tried what `/\p{scx=Han}/`can get, as [Script_Extensions](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr24/#Script_Extensions) explains, but I **only** got 2 more Chinese punctuations, `《 》` while missed other Chinese punctuations.

@WiktorStribiżew's answer may explain that as these two punctuations `《 》` fall in the range of *CJK Symbols and Punctuation* while other Chinese punctuations fall in *Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms range*. But I still think that is a bug for `/\p{scx=Han}/`

Comment: Just create a character class out of the Chinese punctuation chars. It seems most convenient since they are not that many. Also, it will be compatible with more ECMAScript standards.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is what I thought now, but I was hoping maybe there is already some solution out there.

Comment: Ok, what about just excluding ASCII punctuation/symbols? ``/[^\P{P},.\/\\?;':"[\]{}!@#%&*()_-]/u``? This will match any Unicode punctuation symbols other than ASCII.

Comment: Another idea: if [CJK Symbols and Punctuation](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U3000.pdf) is what you are after, you can use `/\p{P}(?<=[\u3000-\u303F])/u`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `/\p{P}(?<=[\u3000-\u303F])/u` seems to work, let me further test it and get back to you! Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you want to include [half- and full-width](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf) punctuation, use `/\p{P}(?<=[\u3000-\u303F\uFF00-\uFFEF])/u`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was about to say /\p{P}(?<=[\u3000-\u303F])/u won't work as we need to add full-width and you added your comment!  YES /\p{P}(?<=[\u3000-\u303F\uFF00-\uFFEF])/u work. How about you add your answer and I accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to match *punctuation proper* that belongs to the [*CJK Symbols and Punctuation*](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U3000.pdf) set, or a [*Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms*](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf) charset, you can use

```js
/\p{P}(?<=[\u3000-\u303F\uFF00-\uFFEF])/u
```

where

- `\p{P}` - matches any punctuation proper char (i.e. it does not match math symbols like `+` or `=`, etc.)
- `(?<=[\u3000-\u303F\uFF00-\uFFEF])` - a positive lookbehind that requires the char matched by `\p{P}` to fall in either the `\u3000-\u303F` (CJK Symbols and Punctuation) or `\uFF00-\uFFEF` (Halfwidth and Fullwidth Forms) range.

See a JavaScript demo below:

```js
const str = "你好，让我们试试这个分词效果，你说怎么样？Let's try Intl.Segmenter, should we ?"
let segmenterZH = new Intl.Segmenter('zh', { granularity: 'grapheme' })
let segments = segmenterZH.segment(str)
for (let segment of segments) {
  if (/\p{P}(?<=[\u3000-\u303F\uFF00-\uFFEF])/u.test(segment.segment)) {
    console.log(`${segment.index}:${segment.segment}`)
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2:，
14:，
20:？
```

---

**`v` flag supoport scenario**

If your JavaScript environment supports [the `v` flag](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag), you can use a character class intersection:

```js
const str = "你好，让我们试试这个分词效果，你说怎么样？Let's try Intl.Segmenter, should we ?";
for (let m of str.matchAll(/[\p{P}&&[\u3000-\u303F\uFF00-\uFFEF]]/gv)) {
   console.log(`${m.index}:${m[0]}`)
}
```

Comment: One thing I have not fully got is `/\p{P}(?<=[\uFF00-\uFFEF])/u` seems enough as I have tested all the Chinese punctuation I can think of. So why we don't need `\u3000-\u303F` here ?

Comment: @Qiulang I explained what that does in the answer, also cf. the [regex without the "CJK Symbols and Punctuation" support](https://regex101.com/r/XB8x7z/1) vs. [with this support](https://regex101.com/r/XB8x7z/2).

Comment: What I would like to argue is that  the claim`\u3000-\u303F`  for CJK Symbols and Punctuation seems not correct at least not for Chinese Punctuation. Because Chinese Punctation always use fullwidth form so they are in `\uFF00-\uFFEF` not in `\u3000-\u303F`

Comment: @Qiulang I have contacted my colleague who is a Chinese expert, and he states that the half/fullwidth part does not cover the `"【 】 〔 〕 《 》"` Chinese punctuation characters that the CJK Symbols and Punctuation covers. (He also includes `≦` and `≧` chars, but these are from the `\p{S}` category.)

Comment: Hi I further think about your answer and still have 2 questions. First https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups and https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind seem to called your regex **lookahead** not **lookbehind**. Second, no matter it is lookahead or  lookbehind they are to check the **next** character, while your regex is to **further** check the matched character, so I am still amazed why that works!

Comment: @Qiulang My regex is not called anyhow, it just contains a Unicode category/property class (`\p{P}`) and a positive lookbehind (`(?<=...)`). You are amazed because you think a my lookbehind is a lookahead.

Comment: Oh, so your lookbehind actually looks for anything(or nothing) as long as it was preceded by Chinese punctuation. Now I fully understand. How clever!

Comment: https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag#intersection  is what I was looking for. It is easier to understand than lookbehind. Thanks!